# How to define dynamically the title in a NavigationView on Sencha Touch?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm using the component of SenchaTouch NavigationView.
The problem I have is I can not define the title of my view dynamically.
This is the code I'm using

```
onMyList: function(dataview, index, target, record, e, options) {
    var myScreen = this.getMyScreen();
    var model = Ext.getStore('Example').getAt(index);
    dataview.up('navSample').config.title = model.data.Nombre;
    dataview.up('navSample').push(myScreen);
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to upgrade Sencha Touch to at least 2.0.1.
than you could use:

```
var navbar = navigationView.getNavigationBar();

navbar.setTitle('My cool title');
```

Cheers, Oleg

Comment: @TDeBailleul no, on pop it will not work :( Only for current view state