# How to set the title for the navigation bar of the panel dynamically

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-theming

I have implemented my application in **sencha touch**

in my panel i have a navigation bar i want to set title dynamically on panel header

[image]

```
 Ext.define('FleetSyncApp.view.WSMachineTypes', {

        extend: 'Ext.Panel',
        alias: 'widget.wsmachinetypes',
          id: 'myPanel',


    config: {
        layout: {
                   type: 'vbox'
                },

        items: [


            {
                title: 'Contact information',
                xtype: 'list',

----
----
-----


    }
],
    listeners: [
                {
                    fn: 'initComponent',
                    event: 'initialize'
                }
                ]
},
```

and in initcomponent method implemented code to get the component like this

```
    initComponent: function(component, options, wstitle) {


           var bar = Ext.getCmp('myPanel');
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to define dynamically the title in a NavigationView on Sencha Touch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11818641/how-to-define-dynamically-the-title-in-a-navigationview-on-sencha-touch)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work

```
bar.getParent().getNavigationBar().setTitle('Your Title');
```

Comment: this appends another tittle bar to my navbar.. the i got the title but idnt want 2 title bars

Comment: alrady i have nav on previous panel.. when we sect a list item on perevious panel here a navbar comes with back button automatically

Answer (score 0):

Sencha Touch stores the titles of the hidden views in the `backButtonStack` array on the navigation bar component. You can change the title at a certain index in the navigation view like this:

```
navView.getNavigationBar().backButtonStack[index] = newTitle;
```

[I made a Gist](https://gist.github.com/vote539/8351170) with a function that takes care of the internals.